# How to set Apache solr admin password

Tags: solr, sunspot-solr

I an not very familiar with solr. I have installed solr successfully. It is using jetty webserver. My solr version is 4.10.3. It admin page is not protected by password. Anyone can access it. I want to apply a paaword on solr admin. How I will do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**For version below 5**

If you are using solr-webapp then you need to modify *web.xml* file and add these lines:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr Lockdown</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>solr_admin</role-name>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Solr</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

For Jetty server, you need to add below lines in */example/etc/webdefault.xml*

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>**admin-role**</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

Update */example/etc/jetty.xml* file

```
<Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
          <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
          <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
          <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

`/example/etc/realm.properties` :

```
admin: s3cr3t, admin-role
```

Username = *admin* 
password = *s3cr3t*. 
Role name = admin-role

**Solr version 5+**

In latest Solr version folder structure got changed. You will find all files in below folder-path.

{SOLR_HOME}/server/etc/jetty.xml
{SOLR_HOME}/server/etc/webdefault.xml

Create new credential file at `{SOLR_HOME}/server/etc/realm.properties`:

```
admin: s3cr3t, admin-role
```

For more info you can help solr [wiki docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity)

Comment: I am using jetty. I follow your instructions but it did not work for my case

Comment: I have updated answer try putting above changes accordingly and let me know if it works.It is works for me. 
updated url   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>.

Comment: I think what might be confusing is that the _only_ text you need to add to realm.properties is `admin: s3cr3t, admin-role`. I was trying to add the entire string, because I'm a noob.

Comment: LandonC I have updated the string for admin and s3cr3t

Comment: Hi Manoj, In the <role-name>core1-role</role-name> you had mentioned core1-role and int realm.properties the role is admin-role will that work?

Comment: This is working, admin is now secured, but also the REST endpoints (such as example.com:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true) are now under authentication. How can I just secure the admin web interface, but leave the  REST endpoints without authentication?

Comment: In solr 5 there is not `etc` folder in `/opt/solr` or its sub directories. Please tell a solution for solr 5

Comment: @Ankit You can check below folder directory and update the details accordingly.
/opt/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml

Comment: You should replace `core1-role` by `admin-role` in `webdefault.xml`

Comment: I followed the same steps and when i try to login I get this error           ""Problem accessing /solr/. Reason: !role " Can anyone help please

Comment: This worked for me. But instead of changing the webdefault.xml, I made all the changes in the path wherefrom the solr is running.  `/opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xm`l, `/opt/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml` and `/opt/solr/server/etc/realm.properties`. Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: If not working, Create creds file in /opt/solr-6.6.2/server/etc/realm.properties

Comment: @capooti, did you get any solution for the use case you mentioned. I want to implement the same

Comment: @MuthuPrasanth I am now using nginx and it correctly works by using auth_basic and auth_basic_user_file

Comment: will it work for solr7.4.0, because after adding all above properties my solr is not starting

Answer (score 27):

**Enable authentication in solr admin running with solr 6.1 and jetty**

**Pre condition:**

1. Solr version 6.1
2. Solr is running successfully in the system
3. Solr Admin running through jetty

Process:

**1.    Edit jetty.xml**

Edit the file “server/etc/jetty.xml”
Add following before the **Configure** tag ends

```
<Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
          <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
          <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
          <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

**2.    Edit webdefault.xml**

Edit the file “server/etc/webdefault.xml”
Add following before the **web-app** tag ends

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>core1-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

**Special Note:**

Value used in the **role-name** tag need to be same used in **“realm.properties”** file

**3.    Create new file  “realm.properties”**

Create a file named “realm.properties” in the location  “server/etc/” and put the below content

```
admin: admin123,core1-role
```

**User Name:** admin

**Password:** admin123

**Role name:**  core1-role

(This need to be same as the name used in **role-name** tag in  server/etc/webdefault.xml” file )

**4.    Final Step**

Restart Solr server

Now access Solr in your browser *http://localhost:8983/solr/*
You will find the browser is asking for `username` and `password`. Enter the `username` and `password`.

[image]

Comment: What are the first two steps for?

Comment: Password hashing is also accepted - admin: MD5:<yourhashedpassword>,<role>

Comment: Is it possible to white-list this authentication for a certian range of IP addresses ?

Comment: If its not working, Create creds file in /opt/solr-6.6.2/server/etc/realm.properties

Comment: It's not working, the page (after restarting the server), shows a 503 error "Service Unavailable" (version 7.4.0)

Comment: This also seems to be broken on Solr 8.1.1 - the system doesn't start with the changes shown above.

Comment: On Solr 8.8 I got **error at <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>** . Once that line in jetty.xml was removed, the server started and prompted me for a login!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using tomcat,

```
Open [Tomcat install dir]\tomcat-users.xml for editing.
```

Add the following lines within the `<tomcat-user>` element and save the changes (using your own username and password):

```
<role rolename="solr_admin"/><user username="your_username"  password="your_password"  roles="solr_admin"/>
```

Open Tomcat install dir\webapps\solr\WEB-INF\web.xml for editing.
"solr" in the path is the name of the instance you want to secure. Typically this is "solr," but may be different if you are running an advanced setup. 
Add the following lines within the `<web-app>` element:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Solr Lockdown</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>solr_admin</role-name>
  <role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>Solr</realm-name></login-config>
```

Save the changes and restart Tomcat. Test your changes by starting a new browser session and navigating to your site, for ex. http://localhost:8080/solr/ You should be prompted for credentials.

If your Tomcat install dir tomcat-users.xml file is being modified then
go to tomcat-users.xml file under Servers in Project Explorer and add your changes there.

Answer (score 4):

As setting a password to Solr is a pain in the ass (sorry, but some time you have to name it as it is) I propose an other solution: Restrict access to it using `iptables`.

If you install Apache Solr Server usually the Server will listen on Port 8983. Hence the servers admin interface will be available under:

```
http://YOUR_SERVERS_IP:8983/solr/
```

So we can restrict connections to port 8983 as follows:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s YOUR_SERVERS_IP --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8983 -j DROP
```

This will accept all requests from localhost (first line) and from the server's IP itself (second line), but drop all other connections (last line). The second line is not necessary but helps us to find easy access to Solr's admin interface. To access the admin interface form a local machine, we have to forward all connections to the server at first. The easiest way to do this, is using sshuttle (lazy mans VPN):

```
sshuttle --dns -r root@YOUR_SERVERS_IP 0/0
```

Performing this command on the local machine, from where we want to access the admin interface.
An other option is, to use `ssh` tunnelling with the open ssh client:

```
ssh -D 1080 root@YOUR_SERVERS_IP
```

Set up a socks proxy in your browser to port 1080.

Comment: If I use above then how it can server to our webclient. That is a website is ajax

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with Solr v.4.10 too and this is really annoyingly hard. None of the so-called "solutions" works for me. I ended up installing Nginx on my Ubuntu box and proxy the :8983 port to docker, where password is required by Nginx. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just to inform what was solution in my case. Actually my website was written in ajax that's why by setting passowrd also protect my website. So its not the solution in case where solr has to be used by open internet. So its best solution as guided by [solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity) is to use proxies like node.js, nginex etc. as given [here](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Solr-proxies)

Using node.js proxy and applying iptable rules ( as guided above) solve my problem.