# Solr 6.1 admin page authentication

Tags: security, solr

I need to implement username and password to Solr admin page in Solr 6.1. How to implement this?

Comment: Documentation : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Securing+Solr

Comment: Quick solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043957/how-to-set-apache-solr-admin-password