# Credentials for Solr admin is not working

Tags: authentication, solr, solrcloud

we have followed answer2 steps in this link, it is not working for Solr Cloud 6.0.3 environment.

[How to set Apache solr admin password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043957/how-to-set-apache-solr-admin-password)

But it is working  fine in normal Master/Slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SolrCloud mode you should use the built-in [Authentication and Authorization support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin).

You enable it by uploading a `security.json` file to your Zookeeper ensemble:

```
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}],
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}
```

There are [several different authentication plugins available](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Authentication+and+Authorization+Plugins) - the example is from the BasicAuthentication module.

Comment: Changing security-edit to all in permissions, will restrict everything.  "permissions":[{"name":"all",

Comment: @MastLindh , I am trying to implement solr authentication. I am using solrcloud. I have uploaded above security.json to zookeeper, but still admin page doesn't ask any username,password. Should I create a separate usermane, password and role in any file

Comment: @MuthuPrasanth The comments is not the place to ask a new question - if you have a question, ask a new question. That way more people will see it and you might get a proper response. Make sure to include the necessary information about what you've tried and what any errors are (check the logs).

Comment: @MatsLindh I have created a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240237/solr-deletes-already-created-shards-when-changing-memory-size. please give your suggestion there asap.I can't figure out nearly past 2 days, expecting your help