# Solr deletes already created shards when changing memory size

Tags: memory, sharding, solrcloud

I am using solrcloud in 5.5.5 version. I have created a collection with two shards with default memory size of 512m. Then my shards got huge data from other system. Now I have 1.2 million documents. I got out of memory error. So I increased SOLR_HEAP (SOLR_HEAP="2g") in solr.in.sh file. After some time, I have noticed that, two created shards got removed from disk. Please anyone have idea about this

Comment: When you say "default memory of 512m" - what do you mean. Was the original Heap size 512m?

Comment: @kellyfj Yes I mentioned Heap size

Comment: I have used Solr 5.3.1 extensively and have not seen any case where shards were removed from the disk during or after a Heap OOM issue. I would suggest looking at the Solr/Lucene logs to see if there are any clues about what happened.